# How does one correctly import data into h2o client in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, analysis, h2o

I am trying to upload csv into h20 server from a client running n R from the RStudio. This is how it looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(h2o)

localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "127.0.0.1", port = 54323)
market_data_file = system.file("extdata", "bank_customer_data.csv", package = "h2o")

market_data  = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = market_data_file, key = "market_data")

class(market_data)

summary(market_data)
```

The output on the console shows the following read out:

> market_data_file = system.file("extdata", "bank_customer_data.csv", package = "h2o")
>
> market_data  = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = market_data_file, key = "market_data")
>   Error in h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = market_data_file, key = "market_data") : 
>     unused argument (key = "market_data")
>
> class(market_data)
>   Error: object 'market_data' not found
>
> summary(market_data)
>   Error in summary(market_data) : object 'market_data' not found

Is there anything am doing wrong?

Comment: You can find the sample examples using  `R` and `h2o` here: https://github.com/chauhansaurabhb/Analysis-of-H2O-vs-SparkMLlib

Comment: `system.file("extdata", "bank_customer_data.csv", package = "h2o")` returns "". There is no dataset like this in the h2o package.

Comment: Try something like this: `market_data  = h2o.importFile(path ="path to your file", destination_frame = "market_data ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is not a parameter in `h2o.importFile`, which is why you are getting the `unused argument` error. Here are the current parameters

```
  h2o.importFile(path, destination_frame = "", parse = TRUE, header = NA,
  sep = "", col.names = NULL, col.types = NULL, na.strings = NULL,
  decrypt_tool = NULL)
```

all of which is explained in the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.importFile.html)

As others have noted in the comments "bank_customer_data.csv" doesn't exist in the h2o package which is why `system.file` is not returning anything.

You should try to import a file you know exists using the process you have above, and see if that works for you. Otherwise if you want to use a dataset in the R package take a look at an example in the R docs for example

```
h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE)
prosPath = system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package = "h2o")
prostate.hex = h2o.importFile(path = prosPath, destination_frame = "prostate.hex")
class(prostate.hex)
summary(prostate.hex)
```